# importing a text dump impossible due to slash comments

Tags: mysql, import, phpbb3, vanilla-forums

i exported a phpbb3.2 forum with the vanilla2 forum exporter.
i got a nice export.txt.gz
extracted it,
and tried to import the 40Mo file with the command line into my "test" database:

> mysql -uroot -p test < export_forum_2016-12-31_054650.txt Enter
>   password:  ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near '// Export Started: 2016-12-31
>   05:46:50 Table: User UserID:int,LastIPAddress:varc' at line 1

but the interpreter bugs upon the "//" style of comments in the import text file, it does not understand it and blocks the import.
exemple:

> // Exported Table: Role (13 rows, 00:00.00)

how could i make it work?

-ubuntu 16.04
-mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.16, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Comment: it seems like a csv, or not ? if it csv you can import with mysqlimport. cabn you us post the first 10 line of you file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the answer from the FAQ of the vanilla exporter,
the file generated by the exporter is a .txt.gz
we should not unzip it to make it work in the importer.

i tried to import the extracted .txt file, but the exporter does not plans to use it that way. you should use the "import" section of a fresh install of your vanilla 2 forum, upload your .gz file in the "uploads" folder of your forum,
and use it in the admin import interface.